# Using data from another sheet in Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to write a SUM function in sheet B, summing all the data from sheet A in specific rows. I can't find a good explanation of how to do this.

Comment: Please vote for the answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to "retrieve" specific rows, then you need to use the following formula.

### Formula

```
=SUMIF(range, criteria, sum_range)
=SUMIF(DATA!A:A,"<="&10,DATA!A:A)
```

### Explained

In this case, the specific rows are summed , only if the value is smaller or equal to 10.

### Example

I've created an example file for you: **[SUMIF](https://docs.google.com/a/jacobjantuinstra.nl/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AluAYY6ZHeWYdHktMU9Wc1BOSVNIeFZnNW5WVEZ0YXc&usp=sharing)**

Answer (score 8):

Try the solution on [this page](https://docs.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=75943&topic=1361471), i.e.:

```
=sum(Sheet1!D7:D8)
```